# Serverless framework deployment error: You're not authorized to access this resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, serverless-framework

When I deploy my serverless framework project using AWS as provider I get:

**You're not authorized to access this resource. - Please contact support and provide this identifier to reference this issue BLAHBLAH**

I am logged into Serverless framework with `serverless login`

My serverless.yaml:

```
org: vladimirorg
app: vladimirapp
service: backend-rest

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  apiGateway: {
    shouldStartNameWithService: true
  }

  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    DYNAMODB_LOCAL_PORT: 9000
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"

functions:
  create:
    handler: src/handlers/create.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: post
          cors: true
          request:
            schema:
              application/json: ${file(src/schemas/create.json)}
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found the root cause - if you wish to deploy serverless framework application you must use the exact same organization (org) and application name (app) as one you registered with serverless framework.

To find out your current app/org name, change them or create new app/org login to Serverless Framework’s dashboard account on `https://app.serverless.com/` using same credentials you use for deploying and make sure you are using the exact org and app in your `serverless.yaml` file:

```
org: orgname  <---
app: appname  <--- 
service: backend-rest
...
```

So you can't just use any arbitrary org/app name, you must use exact org/app registered with Serverless framework.

Answer (score 5):

I had to remove `org: <org>` in order for it to ask me again next time `sls` is run.

Comment: This is the correct answer is your project never used the Serverless dashboard and you start seeing the OP's error.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `serverless logout` or deleting the `~\.serverlessrc` file then run `serverless login` again and try your command

Comment: Tried that as well, for me it was a different app/org name then those registered with serverless framework.

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify AWS profile in your `serverless.yml`, and set your AWS account credential in `~/.aws/credentials` like below:

```
[your_preferred_profile_name]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAZEIJOWEFJOIWEF
aws_secret_access_key=siAOEIF4+TdifOHeofoe+iJR8yFokT7uBmV4DEZ
```

And speciffy this profile in your `serverless.yml` file like this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  profile: your_preferred_profile_name
```

The error you are getting is saying sls framework couldn't access to your AWS resources.
It means you didn't setup this AWS account credential in your local environment and serverless framework.